# refreshing application to use latest update

Tags: jboss, tomcat7, openshift, youtrack

I have tried the following ways to restart the application

rhc app-restart
restarting from the gui after login
I have also restarted the application after logging into the command line and then using ctl_app restart command...

However I am unable to refresh my application to the latest version ...

My application is Youtrack.war which was working perfectly before I updated to Youtrack 5. I have used the same Youtrack 5 war file on another cartridge and it works just fine (except for a minor bug discussed below ).. However I want it to work on the former cartridge because my data is present there .. and I would like to update from youtrack 4 to 5 ..

on youtrack 5 during installion it asks me to set MaxPermSize to 150M .. How do I do that on openshift tomcat container.. I'm using Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) on openshift..

Answer (score 1):

How are you deploying your new war file?  Also, you can check the logs to see what's going on:  https://www.openshift.com/faq/how-to-troubleshoot-application-issues-using-logs

MaxPermSize can be set via JAVA_OPTS variable.  You can export that variable from a pre_start_jbossews hook by creating a file in your repo_dir/.openshift/action_hooks/pre_start_jbossews